# Can't browse my site outside of my country

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, web-hosting, ping

I've hosted an `asp.net mvc 4` website on `IIS 8` and it's perfectly running from my country. But whenever someone tries to browse from other countries, it's not working. [This is my site](https://www.getawesomehome.com). I've allowed port 80 and 443 both in my firewall.

I've also tried pinging from [locaping.com](http://www.locaping.com/) and I get 100% packet loss for every country. Am I missing something that's causing my website unreachable to other countries?

Comment: You say "outside of my country" - have you actually checked it from elsewhere in your country? Or only from your local computer? Have you tried it from a variety of different ISPs within your country as well?

Comment: I've a friend in USA that tried browsing and pinging both and found timeout in both cases. I've also used locaping for pinging from multiple regions. So, yes I'm pretty much sure about what I'm stating.

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't answer my question. I don't disagree - it's certainly _not_ working from outside your country. I asked are you sure it's working from _inside_ your country? Why do you think it's working _inside_ but not outside? What tests have you done to prove it's working inside your country?

Comment: Thanks, I've tested from a lot of people I know in my country. All of them are ok. So I'm 100% sure that there's no problem inside from my country.

Comment: @SinOscuras Are you certain those people are using different ISPs?

Comment: @kasperd, yes I'm sure!

Answer (score 2):

For what i can see, your server is hosted in Bangladesh (whois 43.225.150.107, IRT-WORLDNETBANGLADESH-BD).

Trying a traceroute the last hop i see is in Bangladesh too, it's 125.17.96.94.

Seems you have to ask your provider about this.

In the meantime if you have administrator access to the machine you can sniff the traffic coming and check for connections / packets from outside your country, you can ask some friend or such, or with locaping.

I am not used to windows but for what i remember [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) used to work fine for sniffing last time i checked.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but please can you explain what is wrong here? I'm actually a Web Developer, don't have in-depth concept about networking.

Comment: Updated my answer with a suggestion. But anyway, if it's your provider blocking the traffic only them can solve your problem. Or you can change provider.